# Let $(K_1,d_1),\dots,(K_n,d_n)$ be compact metric spaces. Let $K=K_1\times K_2\times \dots \times K_n$ . Show that $(K,D)$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I want to show this using the following definition for D:

For $x,y\in K$, $D(x,y):= \sum_{i=1}^{n}d_j(x_j,y_j)$. (since the elements of K are like vectors)

I've seen a few different proofs that the cartesian product of finitely many compact metric spaces is compact, none of which rely on this notion of distance.

Also, might it be sufficient to show this is true for any TWO compact metric spaces, from which a more general conclusion may follow?

Any help here is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking if the product of finitely many metrisable compact spaces is metrisable compact or that the product of countable many metrisable compact is metrisable compact?

Comment: The former. $n<\infty$.

Comment: In fact this is true for arbitrary topological spaces, not just metric spaces. See Theorem 26.7 in Munkres' *Topology*.

Comment: I want to give a proof relevant to the space (K,D) in particular.

Comment: What are the $d_j$ for $j>n?$

Comment: ohh the upper on the summation I gave should be n, not $\infty$ I'll fix that

Comment: since each element of $K$ is an n-tuple

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the notion of compactness is purely topological, and in most text books one shows the general theorem that any product of compact spaces is compact. The metric case finite product case is not really easier to prove than the general argument would have been, so it's mostly not done as such.

A metric approach would be to show first that if $(x^{(m)}_1,x^{(m)}_2,\ldots, x^{(m)}_n)_n$ is a sequence in $\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$, then it converges to $(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)$ iff for all $i \le n$ we have $x^{(m)}_i \to x_i$, and use this to show that 
if all $X_i$ are complete, so is $\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$ in this sum metric. Here the finiteness of the product is used quite a bit (to take maximums of finitely many indices or to split $\varepsilon$ in $n$ parts of $\frac{\varepsilon}{n}$ etc.) , but this can be extended to countable products when we choose a better metric on the countable product. Finally show that if all $X_i$ are totally bounded, so is the finite product, and use that for metric spaces totally bounded + complete is equivalent to compactness.

So a treatment within metric spaces theory is quite possible but unnecessary from a general perspective. It could be illustrative, though. Try the arguments I sketched. You can also note that the metric $d_{\infty}(x,y)=\max_{i=1}^n (d(x_i, y_i))$ on the finite product is equivalent to the sum metric $D$ (as $d_\infty \le D \le nd_\infty$ on all pairs of vectors) and this can be slightly more convenient in arguments (it's clearer that this metric induces the product topology as

$$B_{d_\infty}(x,r)=\prod_{i=1}^n B_{d_i}(x_i, r)$$

for instance, so $D$ also does, being (uniformly) equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it for two metric spaces. Then one could easily generalise.

If $(x_n,y_n),n\in\mathbb N$ is a sequence in $K_1\times K_2$,  then $\{x_n\}$ possesses a convergent subsequence $x_{k_n}\to x\in K_1$. Next, $\{y_{k_n}\}$ also possesses a convergent subsequence $y_{k'_n}\to y\in K_2$, which is a sub-subsequence of $\{y_n\}$. Clearly $(x_{k'_n},y_{k'_n})\to (x,y)\in K_1\times K_2$.